# Pusher with multi-database companies

Tags: javascript, php, pusher

I'm trying to figure out what's the best approach to use Pusher in my application.

1. My app consists in a normal website where users log in
2. Each user is connected to a company
3. Each company has its own database

So, I need my app to allow the send of regular messages and notifications (like popups) to people that only belong to the company signed for.

Doubts/problems:

1. If I create a channel called `notifications` and send events to it, all users (no matter what company) will receive it
2. If I set up some sort of token associated to the company won't work because some notifications/messages should only be sent to a restrict users

In my previous project I associated a token to the company because there was no activity between users only a "show-off" of what PHP was doing (within a loop) in each company, something like:

**PHP:**

```
$this->pusher->trigger($company_pusher_token, 'feedback', $data);
```

**JS:**

```
var token   = $('#company_pusher_token').val();
var channel = pusher.subscribe(token);

channel.bind('feedback', function(data) 
{
   alert('working..');
});
```

So, how should I proceed to accomplish what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are going in the right direction.

The channel name would always start with the company unique prefix. If only a subset of users of that company should be notified then combine the prefix with the group ID.

Channels:

- "`notifications`": send to all companies, all clients
- "`<company-token>-notifications`": send to all clients from a given company
- "`<company-token>-<group-id>-notifications`": send to all clients from a group within a given company

By the way if you want to make sure your customers can't bind to another company's channel make sure either the company token is not guessable, or use the "private-" prefix to let you control the authorization on the subscription of channels.